# TYPO3 bootstrap_package and custom page title

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have one problem. I need to setup a custom title tag (it must look like a breadcrumb `<title>` first level page, second level page) in my TYPO3 installation.
In old website I was using this code:

```
#navpath in title tag
config.noPageTitle = 2
page.headerData.11 =HMENU
page.headerData.11.special = rootline
page.headerData.11.1 = TMENU
page.headerData.11.1.wrap =<title>&nbsp;|&nbsp;- &nbsp;Narty.pl</title>
page.headerData.11.1 {
NO {
    allWrap = |,&nbsp; |*||*| |
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    }
}
```

How to implement it to use with pageTitle variable in bootstrap_package

*TYPO3 version: 6.2*

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is right. You just have to add

```
page.10.variables.pageTitle >
```

This removes the TypoScript configuration for pageTitle.